# Operate on one dataframe based on the condition in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, indexing

I have two dataframes: one for days & another for distance. First dataframe contains difference in days about when an activity is performed at a location & second dataframe contains distance between different locations. Both the dataframes are in the form of matrices of about 60,000*60,0000 records. Please see below for an example with 5 locations:

Days difference Matrix

```
    location 1  location 2  location 3  location 4  location 5
location 1  0       3              -5                0             2
location 2  3       0               9                2            -3
location 3  -5      9               0                0            -5
location 4  0       2               0                0             6
location 5  2      -3              -5                6             0
```

Distance matrix

```
    location 1  location 2  location 3  location 4  location 5
location 1  0      64              46                69             68
location 2  64      0              31               100             36
location 3  46     31               0                78             41                                     
location 4  69    100              78                 0             53
location 5  68     36              41                53              0
```

I want to compare the days difference between each location pair from dataframe 1 and if the difference is negative, I want to change the distance value for that pair in dataframe 2 to 1,000.

For example, since the record (3,1) in  dataframe 1 is negative, I want to change the record (3,1) in dataframe 2 to 1,000.

Index names and column names are same in both the dataframes.

I am currently doing it using two nested for loops. This is what I am doing:

```
for i in range(len(days_difference)):
    for j in range(len(days_difference.columns)):
        if days_difference.iloc[i,j] > 0 :
            continue
        else:
                df_dist_matrix.iloc[i,j] = 1000
```

What is a better/more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the index and columns are aligned:

```
dist_diff[days_diff < 0] = 1000

dist_diff
            location 1  location 2  location 3  location 4  location 5
location 1           0          64        1000          69          68
location 2          64           0          31         100        1000
location 3        1000          31           0          78        1000
location 4          69         100          78           0          53
location 5          68        1000        1000          53           0
```